# Best Resources for Learning Mathematics Behind Weather Forecasting

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, atmospheric-science, weather

Anyone know what the standard texts and papers are for understanding how modern ie numerical weather forecasting is done?

Comment: From what angle would you like to approach this? Developing new methods? Applying existing ones? Interpreting results? Incorporating field measurements?

Comment: to understand the current literature up to the point of being able to develop new methods @tpg2114